# How to access universal link in iOS application?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, xcode10, ios-universal-links

I am working with universal link to open iOS application and on this basis of link data I have to open viewcontroller in my iOS application.

I am using Xcode 10.0. And running application on iOS 12.0 (iPhone 7 Plus).

This is my universal link: https://en5vz.app.goo.gl/kjvaHzXrLMNBEDtG7

When I tap on this link then application is launched but method given below is not being called:

```
private func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

    print("\(#function) ---- \(userActivity.webpageURL)")
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        print("\(#function) ---- \(userActivity.referrerURL)")
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }


    if let incominURL = userActivity.webpageURL{

        let linkHandled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks()?.handleUniversalLink(incominURL, completion: { (dynamiclink, error) in

            if let dynamiclink = dynamiclink, let _ = dynamiclink.url{

                self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamiclink: dynamiclink)
            }

        })
        return linkHandled!

    }

    return false

}
```

I am not able to figure out what is the exact issue.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but for anyone looking, the missing component here is the `app-site-association` file: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/enabling_universal_links

> Take the following steps to associate your app and website for universal links:
>
> 1. Add the Associated Domains Entitlement to your app. Include all domains your app will support using the applinks service prefix. See Add the Associated Domains Entitlement.
> 2. Add an Apple App Site Association file to your website. See Add the Apple App Site Association File.
> 3. Add the applinks key to the Apple App Site Association file. Specify the sections of your website each of your apps will handle.

You've done step 1 (and step 0, which is setting up the code in your app), but steps 2 and 3 are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help those in future facing this. I had the same problem where I could open the link to my website using ios App but could not log. 
I found out later that it was the @escaping [Any]? part that caused it.
I changed my code to this instead: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) and it logged to the Xcode console.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: 
NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        print("Continue User Activity called: ")
        if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {
            let url = userActivity.webpageURL!
            print(url.absoluteString)
            //handle url and open whatever page you want to open.
        }

        return true
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

For deep linking I would expect it to call the open url function:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
```

Does that not work for you?

Comment: I love this site, but it blows my mind that the ONLY person to reply, with what is almost certainly the correct answer...gets a down vote?